# How do I know which packages are interfering with the others?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am putting some files together using the following code:

```
data_path <- "daymet"
files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.csv")

daymet <- data_frame(filename = files) %>% 
  mutate(file_contents = map(filename, ~ read_csv(file.path(data_path, .), 
    skip=7)))%>%
  unnest()%>%
  mutate(site = str_sub(filename, 1, 3))
```

At first I had some problems with the error "'GAJPCSR1_2003_2011.csvMapEnv' is not an exported object from 'namespace:maps'". I reinstalled `purrr`. Error gone, everything worked!

I went to put this back with the rest of my analysis, cleared my environment, and when R got to this chunk, the same error message came back.

I've got all these other packages going, so it seems like one of them is not working well with `purrr`. Or maybe not. Even if I don't load all the packages, I still get the same error message.

Session Info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reprex_0.1.1    mapdata_2.2-6   maps_3.2.0      ggmap_2.6.1     soilDB_1.8.5    aqp_1.10       
 [7] stringr_1.1.0   modelr_0.1.0    lubridate_1.6.0 dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.0.0    
[13] tidyr_0.6.1     tibble_1.2      ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1          jsonlite_1.5        splines_3.3.2       Formula_1.2-1      
 [5] assertthat_0.2.0    sp_1.2-5            latticeExtra_0.6-28 backports_1.0.5    
 [9] lattice_0.20-34     digest_0.6.12       RColorBrewer_1.1-2  checkmate_1.8.2    
[13] rvest_0.3.2         colorspace_1.3-2    htmltools_0.3.5     Matrix_1.2-7.1     
[17] plyr_1.8.4          psych_1.6.12        devtools_1.12.0     clipr_0.3.3        
[21] XML_3.98-1.8        broom_0.4.2         raster_2.5-8        haven_1.0.0        
[25] scales_0.4.1        whisker_0.3-2       jpeg_0.1-8          htmlTable_1.9      
[29] withr_1.0.2         nnet_7.3-12         lazyeval_0.2.0      mnormt_1.5-5       
[33] proto_1.0.0         survival_2.41-3     magrittr_1.5        readxl_0.1.1       
[37] evaluate_0.10       memoise_1.0.0       nlme_3.1-131        MASS_7.3-45        
[41] forcats_0.2.0       xml2_1.1.1          foreign_0.8-67      tools_3.3.2        
[45] data.table_1.10.4   hms_0.3             geosphere_1.5-5     RgoogleMaps_1.4.1  
[49] munsell_0.4.3       cluster_2.0.5       plotrix_3.6-4       callr_1.0.0        
[53] rlang_0.1.2         grid_3.3.2          rjson_0.2.15        htmlwidgets_0.8    
[57] rmarkdown_1.5       labeling_0.3        base64enc_0.1-3     gtable_0.2.0       
[61] DBI_0.5-1           reshape_0.8.6       reshape2_1.4.2      R6_2.2.0           
[65] gridExtra_2.2.1     knitr_1.17          rprojroot_1.2       Hmisc_4.0-3        
[69] stringi_1.1.2       parallel_3.3.2      Rcpp_0.12.10        mapproj_1.2-4      
[73] rpart_4.1-10        acepack_1.4.1       png_0.1-7
```

Comment: Maybe include the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Check out `conflicts()` to see if variables are defined in two different environments.

Comment: My guess is that both the `maps` and `purrr` packages have a function called `map()`. you'll need to be careful when loading those -- the last one is the default one you get. Use the full names to be specific `maps::map()` or `purrr:map()`

Comment: `conflicts(detail = TRUE)` might be a complete answer. Is there more you're looking for?

Comment: I tried `conflicts( , detail = TRUE)` and it did look like the problem was with `maps`.

Comment: maybe put as an answer @Gregor? it's a cool function, the world deserve to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see everything that is masking or being masked with

```
 conflicts(detail = TRUE)
```

For example, in my current R session you can see below that I've been answering questions on SO because of all the generic data names in the Global Environment, `df`, `dt`, and `t` masking the base functions of the same name. And you can see data table's `first` and `last` masking the `dplyr` versions, because I loaded `data.table` after `dplyr`:

```
> conflicts(detail = T)
$.GlobalEnv
[1] "n"     "df"    "dt"    "gamma" "t"    

$`package:stringr`
[1] "%>%"

$`package:data.table`
[1] "between" "first"   "last"   

$`package:dplyr`
 [1] "%>%"       "between"   "first"     "last"      "n"         "filter"    "lag"      
 [8] "intersect" "setdiff"   "setequal"  "union"    

$`package:ggplot2`
[1] "Position"

$`package:stats`
[1] "df"     "dt"     "filter" "lag"   

$`package:methods`
[1] "body<-"    "kronecker"

$`package:base`
[1] "body<-"    "gamma"     "intersect" "kronecker" "Position"  "setdiff"   "setequal" 
[8] "t"         "union"
```